# Visual Studio 2013 - IIS Express not serving aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I was compelled by work to upgrade from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.  In VS 2010, I used the built-in host for viewing .net apps locally and everything worked just fine.  Visual Studio 2013 dropped support for the built-in host and compels everyone to use IIS Express.

My trouble is that IIS Express won't serve up "[anything].aspx" no matter where in the folder tree of the project it resides.  I created two test files in the root of the project: HelloWorld.html and HelloWorld.aspx (c#) and made both to simply show a page saying "Hi" with the asp.net file showing the current date and time.  I then copied these two test files into an arbitrary folder in the project.  After building the project (unnecessary, I know), I did a "View in Browser" for all test files.  In all cases, the HTML files displayed properly.  The aspx files cause a "HTTP 400 Bad Request" / "The webpage cannot be found" error.

I've prowled Stack Overflow and Google and read about some near-misses but ultimately came up empty for this specific problem. I'm hoping this is a simple configuration issue, but the answer so far eludes me.  Thanks in advance for your kind assistance!

***Edit:***

Thanks to Lex Li's suggestion of using the Jexus Manager to see what's going on with the IIS Express configuration, it shows that zero apps are assigned to any of the default application pools.  Correspondingly, when clicking on the home of the website in the Jexus Manager, the .Net section of the website is absent.

***Edit #2:***

The web app *is* assigned to one of the default IIS Express app pools: Clr4ClassicAppPool.

Comment: Can you use http://jexusmanager.com to check if the application pool has ASP.NET enabled?

Comment: @LexLi - I used the jexus manager but can't see if asp.net is specifically enabled.  Advanced settings throws an error.  There are 5 app pools started running .net clr version 2 and 4 respectively.

Comment: @anyone - using the jexus manager, I tried changing the 'UnmanagedClassicAppPool from nothing to .Net CLR v4 but it had no effect.

Comment: @LexLi and all - Digging further, comparing resuls from Jexus Mgr with IIS Manager on a real Dev server, I see that the .Net section is completely absent from the IIS Express / Jexus Manager which gels with the # of Applications column showing 0 for all app pools in IIS Express - time for a question-Edit

Comment: 1. In Jexus Manager find the web site that matches the project in your Visual Studio. 2. Check its Basic Settings to see which application pool it uses. 3. Go back to application pool settings to see which ASP.NET runtime this pool uses. As it is in Beta, Jexus Manager always shows 0 application belongs to an application pool. That's  know issue.

Comment: @Lex Li - The app uses Clr4ClassicAppPool.  That pool is set to use .Net CLR v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

Sound weird, did you try open the iis express xml applicationhost.config and check there the mime type or the application pool settings?

Comment: I checked and the defaults all seem to be in order. However, using the Jexus Manager, I saw that for all default app pools, the number of applications per pool were all zero.

Comment: Per Lex Li, the author of Jexus Mgr, the 0 application count is due to the "beta" nature of the software, not because of my particular issue